# Stop mysql MEDIUMINT maxing out to 16777214 on substraction

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have the following question:

```
UPDATE users SET posts = posts - 1 WHERE user_id = 5214
```

However, I think when `posts = 0` this query sets posts to `16777214`. How can I get it to stay @ 0 (it's unsigned) if I try to `-1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply add condition the filters all records which are greater than zero.

```
UPDATE users 
SET    posts = posts - 1 
WHERE  user_id = 5214 AND 
       posts > 0
```